# Is it safe to remove a call to OleInitialize from a non COM static library?

Tags: c++, windows, com, ole, legacy-code

Today I had to define the `WIN32_MEAN_AND_LEAN` preprocessor macro in a native C++ project because I decided to use `boost::asio` in it, and without that macro, I get build errors.

Thing is, the error I get now is `OleInitialize: identifier not found`. According to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms690134%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), this function is used to initialize a COM library. My project is not a COM library now, but my partners say it used to be.

In this case, would it be safe to remove the call? The project uses a mix of Win32 serial port functions and boost::asio (gradually, I'll leave just boost::asio). My concern is that OleInitialize might be necessary for some Win32 calls.

This is all it is done with it:

```
HRESULT hOle = OleInitialize( 0 );
if( !SUCCEEDED( hOle ) )
    throw "Could not initialize OLE";
```

Comment: Simplest solution is to copy/paste the prototypes from MSDN into your own header and carry on calling the functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The worst that will happen is COM methods may start failing, if you're still calling some.  `OleInitialize()` calls `CoInitialize()` internally.  Only those functions need this.  The base Win32 functions (CreateWindow, CreateFile, etc) do not require this initialization.

If you don't call any COM methods (any of the `CoXXX()` functions) and you don't call any Ole methods (`OleXXX()` functions), then you should be fine if you remove it.

You should do a quick search of your code base for COM / OLE functions and make sure you're really not using those technologies anymore.  Then you can make a build where you don't do this and test it to see if it still works (you have a suite of test cases, right?).

Have a look at the [Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for other things that may break that you should check on.

Comment: +1: It seems this call was the last one, and somehow slipped through our looooong refactoring to move from COM to C++/CLI, last year. We do have some automated unit and integration tests, but coverage is still low. I'll chance it this time.

Comment: What does `OleInitialize()` do in addition to calling `CoInitialize()`? I took over legacy code that had both, removed the call to `OleInitialize()`, and things continued to work just fine - would appreciate your insight; thanks.